# Processing framerate very low and not changeable

Tags: performance, audio, processing, frame-rate

I'm building a processing sketch that uses both changing-background-images, oscillators and soundfiles.

Basically every draw(), the background changes, an oscillator plays at a certain frequence and a short audio file is played

Now, the problem: No matter what framerate I set, it always gets below 5. I have an NVIDIA 960 and 16GB of RAM, so I don't really think it's an hardware limitation (?)

Here's my Setup(), where I set the framerate value.

```
     import processing.sound.*;
SoundFile voice;//Quad [] quads;
PImage bg;

//Quad quads;

ArrayList<Quad> quadsArray;
int j=0;
int randomImg;
int randomVoice;
int playVoiceorNot;
TriOsc triangle;
SawOsc saw;
Reverb reverb;
int playSaw;
int timetoChange;
int randomFrate;
int prevVoice;
int screenWidth = displayWidth; 
int screenHeight = displayHeight;



void setup(){
  fullScreen();
  //size(1920,1080);
  //quads=new Quad();
  quadsArray=new ArrayList<Quad>();
  triangle = new TriOsc(this);
  saw = new SawOsc(this);
  triangle.amp(0.1);
  saw.amp(0.1);
  prevVoice=0;
  frameRate(30);
  //background(255);
  //reverb = new Reverb(this);
  bg = loadImage("1.png");
  bg.resize(width,height);
  background(bg);
  triangle.play();
  saw.play();
}


void draw(){
   // println(frameRate);
    //frameRate(60);
    randomImg=floor(random(19));
    //randomImg=4;
    bg=loadImage(randomImg+".png");
    bg.resize(width, height);
    background(bg);
    //filter(INVERT);
    //----controllo se  è tempo di cambiare framerate. Possibilità del 2%----
    //timetoChange=floor(random(100));
   // randomFrate=floor(random(4,15));
     //if(timetoChange>=98){
       //frameRate(randomFrate);
    // }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //pusho un nuovo Quad nell'arrayList-------------------------------------
    quadsArray.add(new Quad());
    //----------PER OGNI QUAD, lo displayo e lo updato-----------------------
    //----------regolo anche la stroke weight in base alla width dei quadrati
    for(Quad current:quadsArray){
      blendMode(MULTIPLY);
      strokeWeight(4);
          triangle.freq(floor(random(100,current.quadwidth/2)));
           saw.freq(0);
          //reverb.damp(0.8);
          //reverb.room(0.7);
         // reverb.process(triangle);
          playSaw=floor(random(100));
          if(playSaw>70){
                saw.freq(floor(random(100,current.quadwidth)));
               // reverb.damp(0.8);
               // reverb.room(0.7);
              //  reverb.process(saw);
                strokeWeight(8);
          }
          else{
             saw.stop();
          }
          current.display();
          current.update();
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //---Ciclo per la gestione dei quads con lifespan terminata-------
    for(int i=quadsArray.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
       Quad temp=quadsArray.get(i);
          if(temp.lifespan<=0){
           quadsArray.remove(i);
          }
    }
    println(quadsArray.size());
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //--controllo se playare una voce o meno. Possibilità del 15%----------------
    playVoiceorNot=floor(random(100));
    if(playVoiceorNot>=85){
        // Load a soundfile from the /data folder of the sketch and play it back
        while(randomVoice==prevVoice){
           randomVoice=floor(random(70));
        }
        prevVoice=randomVoice;
        voice = new SoundFile(this,randomVoice + ".wav");
        voice.amp(1);
        voice.play();
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

and here's the Quad Object:

```
class Quad{

    float x;
    float y;
    float quadwidth;
    float quadheight;
    float lifespan;
    float moving;


  Quad(){ //constructor

   x=width/2;
   y=height/2;
   quadwidth=floor(random(80,width/2));
   quadheight=floor(random(height/2));
   lifespan=255;
   moving=0;

  }

  void display(){
    stroke(255,0,0,lifespan);
    //strokeWeight(3);
    noFill();
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(x,y,quadwidth,quadheight);
  }

 void update(){
   //fill(125,100,30,lifespan);
   lifespan=lifespan-20;
   moving++;
 }

}
```

thanks for the replies!

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]? The code in your post is not runnable.

Answer (score 3):

These two lines are most likely the culprits:

```
bg=loadImage(randomImg+".png");
voice = new SoundFile(this,randomVoice + ".wav");
```

You don't want to load files each frame - it's very slow. Instead, load all files that you may need in setup() (into an `ArrayList` of `PImage` for the backgrounds, for example) and then access them within the *draw()* loop.

I've also found that Processing's image *resize()* function is quite expensive, so call that as you load them in and not within the *draw()* loop.